Do I cut holes in the pcb when using a Meanwell IRM-01-5?
I am making a project that uses a Meanwell IRM-01-5 module, which is a small SMPS in a self-contained module,  which is through-hole soldered to the project's PCB. The module has several holes in the bottom, which I assumed are for ventilation of heat, but I don't really know. Should I have matching holes in the PCB? Otherwise the holes on the bottom of the module will blocked. I'm not sure if that matters.

Does it come with an application note?

As you can read in the datasheet, the module is potted, i.e., filled with silicone. These aren't "air holes", they are where the potting is filled into the device.
Don't leave them free.
However, make sure you're adhering to guidelines on creepage distance, to keep your grid voltage from reaching the low-voltage side. That might (doesn't necessarily have to) entail including a PCB slot under the device; that depends on the board and environment you want to operate it in.

Datasheet does not recommend matching holes, so you do not necessarily need to:

Since they holes are in the mechanical diagram and have the diameters specified, my guess is they're for mechanical support.  Given that this is a compact, transformer isolated device that may require cutouts for isolation, there are probably scenarios where you'd want to be able to provide additional supports (e.g. for impact resistance).
